# deserialization of string array in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a string array of the form

```
"education_history":
     [{"name":"xxxxxx",
       "concentrations":[],
       "school_type":"College"},
     {"name":"xxxxxxx",
      "concentrations":[],
      "school_type":"College"}]
```

**I want to deserialize the values name and school_type**. I have already deserialized the values of single value types but I am facing problems with string arrays.**One more  problem is that in my request I have multiple arrays which I want to deserealize.**

Thanks for the help

Comment: This looks like JSON (except for the outer scope, which could be made into valid JSON simply by wrapping in `{…}`). Are you using a JSON parser? If not, you should.

Answer (score 1):

Like marcelo said, using a json parser is the way to go:
http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use diffrent type instead of string.

Byte array with fixed size or StringBuilder type should work.

String is variable-lenght, that is the reason of problems in deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer to **[Deserialization of a Facebook JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341948/deserialization-of-a-facebook-json-string/9342203#9342203)**  also applies for this question

---

Instead of declaring a lot of tiny classes I would go  `dynamic` way. Here is the code for [dynamic json object](http://pastebin.com/6b2fLChA). And the usage would be something like this:

```
dynamic obj = JsonUtils.JsonObject.GetDynamicJsonObject(jsonString);

Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", obj.current_location.city, obj.current_location.state);

Console.WriteLine("EDUCATION");
foreach (var eduHist in obj.education_history)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", eduHist.name, eduHist.year);
}

Console.WriteLine("WORK");
foreach (var workHist in obj.work_history)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}-{2}", workHist.company_name, workHist.start_date, workHist.end_date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you've below class :

```
public class EducationHistory
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string[] concentrations { get; set; }
  public string school_type { get; set; }
}
```

As already suggested by @aL3891, download [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

And do like below :

```
EducationHistory objVal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EducationHistory>(yourJsonString);
```

You can implement Ienumerable on above class to iterate through collection. Check out a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210982/deserialize-json-to-class-that-implements-ienumerable-in-asp-net), how it deserialize using Json.NET. I hope it helps!

Comment: dude if I have multiple values in a json string...then??I was able to deserealize a value corressponding to a single person, but what if I have 500 person education history in a string??

Comment: In that case you might want to create class like below :
    public class Data
    {
      public EducationHistory[] education_history { get; set; }
      //Other Properties
    }
and you would now deserialize your json string to Data class. I hope it helps!

Comment: Are you sure you did exactly that way? Are you getting any error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341948/deserialization-of-a-facebook-json-string

Comment: Would you mind converting 

    public EducationHistory[] education_history { get; set; }
to
public List<EducationHistory> education_history { get; set; }

do the same for likewise properties in your class.